# How high variance effects differential gene expression analysis

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity, small-sample, group-differences, bioinformatics

I was wondering if anyone had any advice on comparing two groups where the variance in once group is high and the variance in the other group is low.

Specifically, I am attempting differential gene expression analysis using EdgeR. I have been using the glmLRT function however while playing with other functions I discovered the BCV was 0.79. My understanding is that using a generalised linear model is probably not a valid method to compare these two groups (each with 5 replicates). Can anyone offer advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two groups, small sample sizes and different variances? What is the ratio between sample variances? You can find some advice from [this list](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=two+group*+uneq*+varian*+answers%3A1+small).

I would guess the distributions are far from normal too? I would maybe try some permutation test,  [some advice in this list](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=permu*+answers%3A1+small+test+two+group*).